# Doesn't recognize BT400 bluetooth dongle

Tags: usb

I have an Asus BT400 adapter which works fine on Windows in my dual-boot system but is not even recognized by lsusb in Ubuntu 14.04.  I got it working once a few weeks ago, but it doesn't work now and I am not sure when it stopped.

Symptoms:

```
$ uname -r
3.13.0-40-generic
$ lsusb
<hangs for a couple minutes, then finally spits out:>
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 004: ID 1bcf:053a Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Targa Silvercrest OMC807-C optische Funkmaus
Bus 008 Device 003: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 2109:3431  
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

meanwhile, the system log printed:

```
14:11:34 ... kernel: [...] usb 5-2: new full-speed USB device number 12 using ohci-pci
14:11:44 ... kernel: [...] usb 5-2: device not accepting address 12, error -110
14:11:44 ... kernel: [...] usb 5-2: new full-speed USB device number 13 using ohci-pci
14:11:59 ... kernel: [...] usb 5-2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
14:12:10 ... kernel: [...] usb 5-2: device not accepting address 13, error -110
14:12:10 ... kernel: [...] usb 5-2: new full-speed USB device number 14 using ohci-pci
14:12:21 ... kernel: [...] usb 5-2: device not accepting address 14, error -110
14:12:21 ... kernel: [...] usb 5-2: new full-speed USB device number 15 using ohci-pci
14:12:31 ... kernel: [...] usb 5-2: device not accepting address 15, error -110
14:12:31 ... kernel: [...] hub 5-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 2
```

I have tried the following recommended steps:

```
$ sudo su -
# modprobe -v btusb
# echo "0b05 17cb" >> /sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb/new_id
# logout
```

In fact, the above logs took place after running them.  But this Linux noob is mystified because
1. /sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb did not exist before running modprobe
2. It did exist afterward with new_id and remove_id as empty text files
3. After the echo, newid contained the expected text 0b05 17cb
4. But the file remove_id was also immediately changed to contain the same text.
5. And, after a reboot, the btusb directory no longer exists.

I'm guessing none of this will be mysterious to an experienced person, but it seemed a bit strange to this noob (especially #4), and potentially relevant.

```
$ lsmod |grep usb    #after a fresh reboot
usbhid                 52659  0 
hid                   106148  2 hid_generic,usbhid

# lsmod | grep usb  #after the modprobe and echo
btusb                  32412  0 
bluetooth             391136  11 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
usbhid                 52659  0 
hid                   106148  2 hid_generic,usbhid
```

One other thing.  If the dongle is plugged in when I boot Linux, all of my other usb devices (keyboard and mouse) fail to start for a few minutes, while the system log is generating error messages like the above.  I can speed this up by simply unplugging the dongle.

Let me know if more diagnostic info is needed.